# Access transparency and location transparency

Tags: sockets, rmi, distributed, distributed-computing, corba

I have the following questions:

1. Is UDP/IP Socket location transparent and access transparent? Why?
2. Is TCP/IP Socket location transparent and access transparent? Why?
3. Is Java RMI location transparent and access transparent? Why?
4. Is CORBA location transparent and access transparent? Why?
5. Is IPC location transparent and access transparent? Why?

I have trouble figuring out the difference between access transparency and location transparency.

I believe access transparency means you can access the remote and
local methods using the same code.

and

Location transparency means that client would not know whether the
procedure is remote or local.

However, this implies that if client is not access transparent then it is also not location transparent and vice-versa.

Please explain the relation between access transparency and location transparency as well.

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: Thanks!! Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is UDP/IP Socket location transparent and access transparent? Why?

No. You have to know the location, and you can deal  with the local object directly without a socket.

> Is TCP/IP Socket location transparent and access transparent? Why?

Ditto.

> Is Java RMI location transparent

Yes.

> and access transparent?

No.

> Why?

'Location transparent' because once you have the stub you don't know where its server is. 'Access non-transparent' because remote access has to deal with `RemoteExceptions:` local access may not have to.

> Is CORBA location transparent and access transparent? Why?

Same answer as for RMI.

> Is IPC location transparent and access transparent? Why?

Define 'IPC'.

Comment: I didn't get why JAVA RMI is location transparent and not access transparent. We fetch remote object reference from RMI Registry by Naming.lookup("rmi://host_name:port_number/name"). So, here client is passing the hostName, which means the client knows about the servers location. Moreover, if the server is migrated to different location then in that case, the hostName would change. Please guide me where I am going wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: (a) The client knows the *registry's* location. The location of the remote object can be different. (b) The remote client must call the remote object via the remote interface, which must throw `RemoteException`. A local client can call the object directly,and the method implementations normally should not throw `RemoteException`.